# Push currentTitle from different Buttons to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi everyone I'am new in objective c and iOS dev. Now i try to create an app like ["What's the word"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-word-new-quiz-pics-word/id573511269?mt=8)
I have a problem with the buttons and places for it. When i click button with Letter at the first time  everything alright ([pic 1], [pic 2]), but at the second time button try to go at the first place, and it's doesn't work ([pic 3]). I want that each next click push the button in the next place (or pass the currentTitle). I try to replace button and use only currentTitle, and the result was ([pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqqAc.png)).
I think (but not sure) the problem in

> -(void)letterView:(LettersView *)letterView didClick:(BOOL)didClick addChar:(NSString *)addChar

but i don't know how to fix it. I'l be grateful for any help.

P.S I attach all images in comments.

My code:

**GameController.m**

```
    #import "GameController.h"
#import "config.h"
#import "LettersView.h"
#import "PlacesView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation GameController {

    //tile lists
    NSMutableArray* _letters;
    NSMutableArray* _places;

}

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.points = [[PointsController alloc] init];
        self.audioController = [[AudioController alloc] init];
        [self.audioController preloadAudioEffects: kAudioEffectFiles];

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)dealRandomWord {

    NSAssert(self.level.words, @"Level not loaded");

    // random word from plist
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random()%[self.level.words count];
    NSArray* anaPair = self.level.words[ randomIndex ];

    NSString* word1 = anaPair[1]; // answer
    NSString* word2 = anaPair[2]; // some letters
    _helpstr = anaPair[3]; // helper

    NSLog(@"qweqweq %@ %@" , word1 , word2);

    NSInteger word1len = [word1 length];
    NSInteger word2len = [word2 length];

    NSLog(@"phrase1[%li]: %@", (long)word1len, word1);
    NSLog(@"phrase2[%li]: %@", (long)word2len, word2);

    //calculate the letter size
    float letterSide = ceilf( kScreenWidth*0.9 / (float)MAX(word1len, word2len) ) - kTileMargin;

    //get the left margin for first letter
    float xOffset = (kScreenWidth - MAX(word1len, word2len) * (letterSide + kTileMargin))/2;

    //adjust for letter center
    xOffset += letterSide/2;
    float yOffset = 1.5* letterSide;


//    init places list
    _places = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: word1len];

// create places
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<word1len; i++){
        NSString *letter = [word1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];


        if (![letter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            PlacesView* place = [[PlacesView alloc] initWithLetter:letter andSideLength:letterSide];
            place.center = CGPointMake(xOffset + i*(letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight/2);

            [self.gameView addSubview:place];
            [_places addObject: place];
        }
    }
    //init letters list
    _letters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: word2len];

    //create letter
    for (NSInteger i=0;i<word2len;i++) {
        NSString* letter = [word2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];


        if (![letter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            LettersView* letv = [[LettersView alloc] initWithLetter:letter andSideLength:letterSide];
            letv.center = CGPointMake(xOffset + i * (letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight/4*3); // "/3*4"
            if (i > 6) {
                letv.center = CGPointMake(-5.15 * xOffset + i * (letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight/4*3 + yOffset); // "/3*4"

            }
            letv.clickDelegate = self;

            [self.gameView addSubview:letv];
            [_letters addObject: letter];
        }
    }

}

-(void)letterView:(LettersView *)letterView didClick:(BOOL)didClick addChar:(NSString *)addChar
{
    PlacesView* placesView = nil;
    for (PlacesView* pl in _places) {
        ///if (didClick) {
            placesView = pl;
            placesView.fieldForLetter.text = [placesView.fieldForLetter.text stringByAppendingString:letterView.clickLetter];
//            didClick = NO;
            NSLog(@"MAIN LOG %@", placesView.fieldForLetter.text);
            break;
        //}
    }
    // check if place was found
    if (placesView!=nil) {

        // check if letter matches
        if ([placesView.letter isEqualToString: letterView.letter]) {
            [self placeLetter:letterView atTarget:placesView];
             [self.audioController playEffect: kSoundLetterTap];

            self.points.points += self.level.coinsPerLvl; //ne nado tak

            NSLog(@"Current points %d" , self.points.points);

             [self checkForSuccess];
        } else {
            [self.audioController playEffect:kSoundFail];
            [self addAlert:@"ne success" andMessage:@"You lose!" andButton:@"ok"];
        }
    }
}
-(void)placeLetter:(LettersView*)letterView atTarget:(PlacesView*)placeView {
    placeView.isMatched = YES;
    letterView.isMatched = YES;

    letterView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
//                          delay:0.00
//                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
//     
//                     animations:^{
//                         letterView.center = placeView.center;
//                         letterView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
//                     }
//     
//                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
//                         placeView.hidden = YES;
//                     }];
}

-(void)checkForSuccess {
//    for (PlacesView* p in _places) {
//        //no success, bail out
//        if (p.isMatched==NO) return;
//    }
//    NSLog(@"ya!");
//    [self addAlert:@"Success" andMessage:@"You win!" andButton:@"eshe cyka"];
//    [self.audioController playEffect:kSoundSuccess];
}

-(void)addAlert: (NSString *)addTitle andMessage: (NSString *)alertMessage andButton: (NSString *)alertButton {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIWindow* window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

        window.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: addTitle message:alertMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *defaultAction= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:alertButton style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            window.hidden = YES;

        }];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
}
@end
```

**LetterView.m**

```
#import "LettersView.h"
#import "config.h"
#import "PlacesView.h"

@implementation LettersView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use initWithLetter:andSideLength instead");
    return nil;
}

-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString*)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength
{
    //the letter background
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_letter@2x.png"];

    //create a new object
    self = [super initWithImage:img];

    if (self != nil) {

        //resize the letters
        float scale = sideLength/img.size.width;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width*scale, img.size.height*scale);

        //more init

        // button right way!!!!!!!!
        UIButton *lblChar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        lblChar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblChar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblChar setTitle:letter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [lblChar addTarget:self action:@selector(displayСhar:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:lblChar];

        self.isMatched = NO;

        _letter = letter;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

// !!!!right way
-(void)displayСhar:(id)sender {
    UIButton *lblChar = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The buttons title is %@",  lblChar.currentTitle);
    _clickLetter = lblChar.currentTitle;
    BOOL didClick = YES;
    if (self.clickDelegate) {
        [self.clickDelegate letterView:self didClick:(BOOL)didClick addChar:_clickLetter];
    }
    NSLog(@"CLICKLETTER %@", _clickLetter);

   }

@end
```

**PlacesView.m**

```
#import "PlacesView.h"
#import "config.h"


@implementation PlacesView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use initwithletter");
    return nil;
}

-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString *)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_input@2x.png"];
    self = [super initWithImage: img];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.isMatched = NO;

        float scale = sideLength/img.size.width;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width*scale, img.size.height*scale);

        //bullshit time
        _fieldForLetter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _fieldForLetter.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _fieldForLetter.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _fieldForLetter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _fieldForLetter.text = @""; // if button pressed button title placed here.
        [self addSubview:_fieldForLetter];

        _letter = letter;

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTaped:)];
        [_fieldForLetter addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) didTaped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture{

    if( [tapGesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
        // the label that was tapped
        UILabel* fieldForLetter = (UILabel*)[tapGesture view];
        // do things with your label
          NSLog(@"SOME ** IN CONSOLE: %@", fieldForLetter);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Image Links : [Pic 1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxIR9.png
  [Pic 2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fPuB8.png
  [Pic 3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/abunA.png

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, if you don't, to use a collection of Ui objects, like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btnCollection;
```